# How can I get this javascript added in my php

Tags: javascript, php

Microsoft says we can use the following javascript to detect Windows 11 (on the client side):

```
navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues(
   ["architecture", "model", "platform", "platformVersion", "uaFullVersion"])
      .then(ua => { console.log(ua) });
```

The response should be like: `platformVersion: "14.0.0"`.

I need to use this as a variable in my PHP to detect if a user is using Windows 11:

```
if(is_browser_request()){   

$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$systemid = $_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM'];
$version = Unknown how to define

if (stripos($user_agent, "iPhone")!==false) {
    $brand = 'iPhone';
} else if ($version == "14.0.0") {
    $brand = 'Win11';
} else if ($version == "10.0.0") {
    $brand = 'Win10';
```

Does this make sense? How can I get the javascript added in my php and define the $version?

Comment: You need to use ajax/xhr request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: You'll also need a [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) to retain the information for the following requests. Also note that the JS code only works in Edge. What is the end goal here? Maybe it can be achieved in a different way.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you sir! This is to detect and show up everyone's system version on my forum. Yep hopefully I could find a new way. It's been very much inconvenient since Windows 11 will use "Window NT 10.0" which is the same that Windows 10 uses.

Comment: I tried to get <meta http-equiv="Accept-CH" content="Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version"> added between <head> and </head>, but it never worked for my webpages.

Comment: HTML is not a programming language, it cannot detect anything. Wouldn't it be easier to just let the user select their OS?